# AFNetworking 2.0 - "unacceptable content-type: text/plain"

Tags: ios, json, node.js, ios7, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFNetworking 2.0 to read JSON from a service I'm building (on `localhost` for now) in Node. Pretty normal stuff.

Node is sending JSON like so:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
res.end( JSON.stringify(...));
```

My iOS first-pass code is attempting to read that data like so:

```
typedef void(^NextBlock)();
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager GET:self.newestTimestampURL.absoluteString
    parameters:nil
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        //NSDictionary *response =
        NSLog(@"got %@", responseObject );
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"fail %@", error );
    }];
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/plain" UserInfo=0xb783e30 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:3000/api/v1/log/newest, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xb656a70> { URL: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/log/newest } { status code: 200, headers {
Connection = "keep-alive";
ContentType = "application/json";
Date = "Fri, 27 Dec 2013 20:58:50 GMT";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/plain}
```

I can curl (-i) the url `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/log/newest` and get the data I'm expecting, and it's application/json as expected. If I load that data in my web browser, I get JSON as expected per dev tools inspector.

But using AFNetworking, I get this mysterious "unacceptable content-type: text/plain" error. Any idea?

NOTE: I've never used AFNetworking before, so I'm probably using it incorrectly.

Comment: If you `curl` with the `-I` flag to just get the headers. Has the response got the correct content type header at this point?

Comment: When I curl -I I get the following: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ContentType: application/json
Date: Sat, 28 Dec 2013 14:26:04 GMT
Connection: keep-alive`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Content-Type` with a hyphen?

Comment: Oh, holy hell. Thanks! I had assumed my client code was at fault, but it was a typo in the node JS code. Thanks so much! A christmas miracle!

Answer (score 40):

It seems that the server is sending "text/html", and this type is not supported by default. Add @"text/html" for "acceptableContentTypes"

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
```

Answer (score 22):

`manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];`

work for me.

Comment: works for me as well, I have used `manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];` but it did not help me. But your solution works.

Answer (score 9):

Work for me.

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];
```

Comment: This works but is a poor solution because it does not add "text/plain" to the list of acceptable types, but replaces it instead, meaning that other valid types - like "application/json" will no longer work. The more correct (and complete) answer is provided by ABS.

Answer (score 4):

Just use:

SWIFT:

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(object: "text/plain") as Set<NSObject>
```

OBJ-C:

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573527/calling-web-services-with-the-help-of-afnetworking-in-objective-c/42573800#42573800

Answer (score 4):

I have followed the answer posted by @KIO but it did not work in my scenario.

After going with many answers i was able to find solution which worked for me.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

AFJSONResponseSerializer *jsonResponseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

NSMutableSet *jsonAcceptableContentTypes = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:jsonResponseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes];
[jsonAcceptableContentTypes addObject:@"text/plain"];
jsonResponseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = jsonAcceptableContentTypes;
operation.responseSerializer = jsonResponseSerializer;
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. It didn't break the existing json types and can be easily adapted to include even more types. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:RSS_WORLD_NEWS];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

// Make sure to set the responseSerializer correctly
operation.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];

operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/rss+xml"];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSXMLParser *XMLParser = (NSXMLParser *)responseObject;
    [XMLParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES];

     XMLParser.delegate = self;
     [XMLParser parse];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving contents"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

}];

[operation start];
```

work for me

Answer (score 0):

***Updated Solution for Swift.***

If you are using AFNetworking in Swift. Then this solution might help you. It will accept most of the content types.

```
let manager=AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

            manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer(readingOptions: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as AFJSONResponseSerializer

            manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer() as AFJSONRequestSerializer

            manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(objects:"application/json", "text/html", "text/plain", "text/json", "text/javascript", "audio/wav") as Set<NSObject>
```