# Can't make right Alamofire request (have right curl)

Tags: swift, alamofire

Alamofire version 5.0.0
I got error when try to make a request

> failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseValidationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableContentType(acceptableContentTypes: ["text/plain"], responseContentType: "text/html")))

My code:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Accept" : "text/plain",
            "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        ]
        
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "login" : "loginName",
        "password" : "password",
    ]    

AF.request("https://link",
                   method: .post,
                   parameters: parameters,
                   headers: headers)
                   
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { (data) in
            print(data)
        }
```

Right Curl request (not mine but should be):

curl -X POST "https://link" 
-H "Accept: text/plain" 
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
-d login=loginName&password=password

**Help me create the right query. Where am I doing something wrong?**

Comment: Read the text that's coming back and see what the error says.

Comment: I can't say this is the reason but it seems that you are expecting `json` as the response format, I get that from `.responseJSON { (data)`, but it seems like your server is sending back `text/html`. This thread have some answers to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807926/afnetworking-2-0-unacceptable-content-type-text-plain perhaps ?

Comment: If you have a working curl, why not "ask" Alamofire to print the cURL command of your request? See https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#curl-command-output and compare But error is explicit, you are receiving text/html instead of text/plain. Print the real reponse, and its either an issue from the server or on your side...